# How to add a common number to rows that have same value in another column?

Tags: r

After years of using your advices to another users, here is my for now unsolvable issue...

I have a dataset with thousands of rows and hundreds of column, that have one column with a possible value in common. Here is a subset of my dataset :

```
ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
Dose <- c("1", "5", "3", "4", "5")
Value <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x2", "x3")
mat <- cbind(ID, Dose, Value)
```

What I want is to assign a unique value to the rows that have the "Value" column in common, like that :

```
ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
Dose <- c("1", "5", "3", "4", "5")
Value <- c("153254", "258634", "896411", "258634", "896411")
Code <- c("1", "2", "3", "2", "3")
mat <- cbind(ID, Dose, Value, Code)
```

Does anyone have an idea that could help me a little ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `match` here

```
library(dplyr)
mat %>% 
    mutate(Code = match(Value, unique(Value)))
```

-output

```
 ID Dose  Value Code
1  A    1 153254    1
2  B    5 258634    2
3  C    3 896411    3
4  D    4 258634    2
5  E    5 896411    3
```

#### data

```
mat <- data.frame(ID, Dose, Value)
```

Comment: Am I wrong or is this easily converted into a base R only solution?

Comment: @MartinGal it can be converted if it is matrix or data.frame using the column names i..e `cbind(mat, Code = match(mat[, "Value"], unique(mat[, "Value"])))`

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a data.frame:

```r
mat <- data.frame(ID, Dose, Value)
```

Using `dplyr` you could create the desired output:

```r
library(dplyr)

mat %>% 
  group_by(Value) %>% 
  mutate(Code = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  ID    Dose  Value   Code
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <int>
1 A     1     153254     1
2 B     5     258634     2
3 C     3     896411     3
4 D     4     258634     2
5 E     5     896411     3
```